# Parsing a tree of groups with PLY Yacc

Tags: python, yacc, ply

The structure I'm trying to parse looks like so:

```
group "a" [
    group "b" [
      group "c" [
      ]
    ]
    group "d" [
    ]
]
```

and the grammar:

```
def p_group(p):
    '''group : GROUP string subgroups'''
    p[0] = DNAGroup(p[2])
    for sgroup in p[3]:
        print p[0].getName(), "subgroup ", sgroup.getName()
        p[0].add(sgroup)
        sgroup.setParent(p[0])

def p_subgroups(p):
    '''subgroups : "[" group
                    | subgroups group
                    | subgroups "]"
                    | "[" "]"'''
    if p[0] is None:
        p[0] = []
    if p[2] != ']':
        p[0] += [p[2]]
```

Each parent has a list of children groups, and each child has a reference to it's parent. I can't seem to get the grammar to go without shift/reduce conflicts and it's not parsing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the definition of subgroups: in the subgroup state, the token GROUP can result in either shifting or reducing (shift taking this as a new group to parse, reduce recognizing subgroups-handled-so-far and leaving GROUP to be rescanned to make a new group), and the token ']' can also result in shifting or reducing (similar reasoning).

I think your intent is such that you can rewrite this as:

```
subgroups : "[" sublist_opt "]"
```

with:

```
sublist_opt : group sublist_opt
            | empty
```

(I leave you to fill in the python code for this grammar fragment).

Comment: That's bringing up an infinite recursion error for symbols group, subgroups, and subgroup_opt(what you called sublist_opt I just renamed it)

Comment: The recursion error was because I was missing an empty rule. This works, except for the fact that it doesn't when a parent has more than one child.

Comment: I called it a sublist_opt rather than a subgroup_opt because it allows zero-or-more `group`s (using left recursion), perhaps `subgroup_list_opt` or just `subgroup_list` would be better :-) ... as for parent with multiple children, I'm not sure what's wrong, the code in `p_group` looks reasonable.

Comment: I figured it out, it needed to be `subgroup_list group` instead of `group subgroup_list`.

Comment: Oh hm, that didn't work either, it just made it use the second subgroup instead of the first.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out for real this time. I was forgetting to set p[0] = p[1] in the subgroup_list rule with `subgroup_list group`

Comment: You'll want `p_subgroup_list` to return (as in set `p[0]` to) a list of all the groups, and since the parse is recursive, that would be something like: `p[0] = [p[1]] + p[2]` for the non-empty case, and `p[0] = []` for the empty case.  (But I've never used PLY, only yacc/bison/etc)